# Makefile does not find rules despire of available files

Tags: gcc, makefile

Currently I am trying to get a rather big project of mine to work with a Makefile. I used Make before but in a rather crude way and not really "dynamic", this means I am pretty new to good Makefiles.

My Makefile looks like this:

```
INCLUDE_DIR = /inc
SOURCE_DIR = /src
BUILD_DIR = /build

BUILD_NAME = build

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
CFLAGS = -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)

_INCLUDES = main.h pfc.h
INCLUDES = $(patsubst %, $(INCLUDE_DIR)/%, $(_INCLUDES))

_OBJ = main.o pfc.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %, $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(_OBJ))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(BUILD_NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

all: $(BUILD_NAME)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

When I make the file I get this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/build/main.o', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

I guess it is an error in this recipe:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Sadly I am not able to get this done on my own.
All files a available in the correct folders.

I really appreciate all the help!

Tristan

Comment: "All files a available in the correct folders." Do you really have directories right under the root filesystem (`/`) of your computer called `src`, `inc` and `build`?

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry ./build in the correct directory. The Makefile is still not able to find the rule.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here that I can see. But first off - just check (just incase) that all your rules are only indented with tabs and not spaces..... this can be a real "silent" killer of makefiles as they give crap error messages.

1. Ok so - lets assume you have:

```
    INCLUDE_DIR = inc
    SOURCE_DIR = src
    BUILD_DIR = build
```

instead of `/src` etc.. as mentioned in the comments.

2. Do you really have inc/main.h and inc/pfc.h?

I copied and pasted your makefile added your src and inc folders (but I used gcc instead of `arm-none-eabi-gcc`. It did the compile lines correctly, but failed at the linker stage because you are trying to build an output file called `build` when there is already a folder called `build` (not allowed in linux - maybe ok for windows but I don't recommend).

3. I made an answer for another question - but it might be a better start point then you have here in the case where you have nested src/inc directories and you want to be able to clean your output folders - ill put it here for convenience:

```
    # Get your source list (use wildcard or what ever, but just for clarity you should end up with a list of files with full paths to start with):

    # Output folders/targets
    SRC_DIR = src
    OBJ_DIR = obj
    BIN_DIR = bin
    OUTPUT_FILE = output

    # Generate list of source files - this is a linux command - but you can do this in pure make using wildcard and such).
    SOURCES := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.c')

    # Create your objects list in the obj directory
    OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES))))

    # Create list of unique folders to create
    DIRS = $(sort $(dir $(OBJECTS))) $(BIN_DIR)

    # Create list of include paths
    INCS = $(addprefix -I,$(sort $(dir $(SOURCES))))

    # Main target rule
    $(BIN_DIR)/$(OUTPUT_FILE): $(OBJECTS) | $(DIRS)
        @echo linker: gcc $(OBJECTS) -o $@
        @touch $@

    # Rule to build your object file - ensure that the folders are created first (also create a dummy obj file) - note this works for parallel builds too (make -j
    $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c | $(DIRS)
        @echo compile: gcc $(INCS) -c $? -o $@
        @touch $@

    # Create your directories here
    $(DIRS):
        @echo Creating dir: $@
        @mkdir -p $@

    # Clean if needed
    .PHONY: clean
    clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
```

**Note** this is just a template, you still need to fill in the gcc/makefile flags - but its a decent start point...

4. Debugging

`$(info ...)` is your friend - for example you could do:

`$(info OBJ = $(OBJ))`

`$(info objrule = $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c $(INCLUDES))`

To print our what make has expanded these variables / lines to be - this can yield useful debug.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I did that: `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c | $(DIRS)`  ... or did I miss something?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin oh yeah - good spot. in this case I think it only triggers a re-link which would happen anyway if a file had changed (probably), but its def more correct to have it - updated : )

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - yeah I put a comment next to that line suggesting there are other options that are pure make, so not too bothered about that. Regarding the objects, no, this keeps the folder structure intact within the objects folder therefore any file with the same name is safe - that's kind of the point in fact : )

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of your makefile with automatic dependency generation:

```
INCLUDE_DIR := inc
SOURCE_DIR := src
BUILD_DIR := build

CC := arm-none-eabi-gcc
CPPFLAGS := -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)

exes := build
build.obj := main.o pfc.o

all : ${exes:%=${BUILD_DIR}/%}

.SECONDEXPANSION:

${BUILD_DIR}:
    mkdir -p $@

# Rule to link all exes.
${exes:%=${BUILD_DIR}/%} : ${BUILD_DIR}/% : $$(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$${$$*.obj}) | $${@D}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} $^ ${LDLIBS}

# Rule to compile C sources. And generate header dependencies.
${BUILD_DIR}/%.o : ${SOURCE_DIR}/%.c | $${@D}
    ${CC} -o $@ -c ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} -MD -MP $<

# Include automatically generated header dependencies.
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(foreach exe,${exes},$(patsubst %.o,${BUILD_DIR}/%.d,${${exe}.obj})) 
endif

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: all clean
```

To add another executable target do:

```
exes += another
another.obj := another_main.o another_pfc.o
```